# What is the basis for $[\mathbb{Q}(ɛ) : \mathbb{Q}]$?

Tags: extension-field

Let ɛ = e<sup>2πi / 5</sup>.

$[\mathbb{Q}(ɛ) : \mathbb{Q}]$ = 4 
I originally thought the dimension was 2 with basis {1, ɛ}, but it is actually 4.  What exactly is the basis, and why is it not {1, ɛ}?

Comment: The degree $[\mathbb{Q}(\varepsilon):\mathbb{Q}]$ is precisely the dimension of $\mathbb{Q}(\varepsilon)$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One basis of that extension is $\{ 1, \varepsilon, \varepsilon^2,\varepsilon^3 \}$. You can see $\mathbb{Q(\varepsilon)}$ as the splitting field of the 5th cyclotomic polinomial:

$$ \Phi_5(x)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x^1+1$$

Which is irreducible and $deg(\Phi_5)=4$, so $\left[ \mathbb{Q}(\varepsilon): \mathbb{Q} \right]=4$.